# Chrome and resources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, resources

I'm using `Google Chrome` to play some videos. I've notice that after a long time playing different videos, my browser uses more and more resources to finish at 100% CPU usage..
After some research, I've found that `Chrome` saves every single read video. Please see my screenshot below:

[image: Google Chrome resources]

I think there are 2 possibilities to explain this.

1. I need to delete all those files manually
2. I'm doing something wrong when I'm switching from a video to another (`javascript`).

Here is some code about my object's destruction that I call overtime before removing my `<video>` tag:

```
# MyVideo.js.coffee
# @element is a DOM element (<video>)
destroy: ()->
  @element.src = ''
  @element.load()

  @element.parentNode.removeChild(@element) if @element.parentNode
  $(@).trigger('destroyed')
  $(@element).off()
  $(@).off()
  @element = null
```

Here is my request headers (keep-alive):
[image: Chrome Headers screenshot]

May the `keep-alive` create such an issue? 
Currently, the only solution I have is to restart my page..

Comment: removing something from the dom does not necessarily mean the browser will remove it from it's cache.

Comment: That's the point. What about cleaning? It seems the garbage collector isn't called at all. That's my 2 points. (Chrome doesn't do it or code problem)

Comment: garbage collector? This is a cache of content downloaded from the internet. It's invisible to your code, as if you tried to get that resource it would simply load it from it's cache instead. I would suggest your problem with CPU does not lie with the fact that Chrome is caching content otherwise every website would have the same problem,

Comment: It is still cached because it's linked to somewhere else (I guess). If not, the garbage collector would have delete instances and (probably) cached files. Can a `keep-alive` connection force Chrome to keep cached files?

Comment: you are missing my point. Open the developer console and inspect the resources tab for this page. Who is managing that content, you or the browser? Hint - it's not you.

Comment: Ok. Then how can I force Chrome to do that without reloading my page?

Comment: A) your problem is not being caused by the number of files in your cache and B) You can't.

Comment: you talk about a garbage collector, but cached resources are not garbage collected. They will be there the next time you visit that page, until the cache evicts them which is something Chrome controls. Ask yourself this question - if you "fixed" it in Chrome, how will you "fix" it in Firefox?

Comment: I just want to fix it in Chrome. It's the only browser I need to fix it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: there is nothing to fix. Caching resources *are what browsers are supposed to do*. Your CPU problem is unrelated. Good luck!